# Hide/Show CircularProgressIndicator onclick Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I want to show CircularProgressIndicator onclick and then hide !the CircularProgressIndicator when the function is executed see code below

```
var loader by remember {mutableStateOf(false)}
if(loader){
   CircularProgressIndicator()
}
Button (onclick {
   loader = !loader // show CircularProgressIndicator
   // Function which is to be executed 
   // After function is executed which usually takes 2 sec then after that CircularProgressIndicator should be hidden
   loader = loader // Not hidding
}){
  Text("Toggle")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to check that in any case at the end of your processing `firebase = false` should be called. I'd advise you at least to move the logic into a separate function, so I'll be harder to make a mistake, but basically it should look something like this:

```
OutlinedButton(onClick = {
    keyboardController?.hide()
    if (emailState.value.isEmpty() && secureState.value.isEmpty())
        return@OutlinedButton
    firebase = true
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            val exception = task.exception?.localizedMessage.toString()
            if (task.isSuccessful)
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.sendEmailVerification()
                    ?.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                        firebase = true
                        if (task.isSuccessful)
                            snackbarCoroutineScope.launch {
                                scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
                                    "Check your Email for Verification")
                            }
                    }
            else
                snackbarCoroutineScope.launch {
                    scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(exception)
                    firebase = true
                }
        }
}) {
    Text(text = "Sign Up")
}
Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(16.dp))
TextButton(onClick = {
    keyboardController?.hide()
    if (emailState.value.isEmpty())
        return@TextButton
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().sendPasswordResetEmail(email)
        .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            val exception = task.exception?.localizedMessage.toString()
            firebase = false
            if (task.isSuccessful)
                snackbarCoroutineScope.launch {
                    scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar("Check your Email for Password reset")
                    firebase = true
                }
            else
                snackbarCoroutineScope.launch {
                    scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(exception)
                    firebase = true
                }
        }
}) {
    Text(text = "Forgot password?")
}
```

Comment: @Unknown how exactly your processing function works? if it's a coroutine, `loader = !loader` should be inside that coroutine, if it's just a blocking function, it should've block your UI and you won't be able to see the progress indicator at all..

Comment: Yes I'm using coroutine

Comment: @Unknown I've updated my answer, if this still doesn't help, please add more code: how the processing function looks like(no processing part needed, just semantics) and how do you execute it

Comment: see my code here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/abhishekumar-dev/Authentication/main/app/src/main/java/com/example/app/LoginView.kt

Comment: Thanks yes i should move the logic to a seprate function thanks for su